# How to launch an application from hashtable in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, launching-application

hey i'm able to create hash table in Objective-C which stores data in XML format...
but how to launch the application which i've specified in the string tag in XML file...My application name is in the bundle format... 
For Example:

```
<key>HelloWordl<key>
<string>HelloWorld.bundle<string>
```

How to launch this HelloWorld.bundle??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSBundle to load the the bundle.

You can do this by the following interfaces:
+ (NSBundle *)bundleWithPath:(NSString *)fullPath
- (BOOL)load

Comment: hi,

i've implemented this interface, but wat is this principalClass concept...stil my bundle is not being loaded ... pls help.

Comment: principalClass - is the bundle interface with which you can interact  with bundle after loading.

- make sure you are giving right path to load.

- are you trying to load bundle created by your self? if yes, make sure bundle creation is correct. 

see if the following link helps in some way:http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000078.php

Comment: yes i'm loading the bundle which i created... for example, i've a project called HelloWorld. i renamed it to HelloWorld.bundle...now i want to access this bundle in my other project...how to do that ? 
i'm finding ways to do it in MAC OS, but how to do it in iPhone OS?

Comment: can u pls elaborate your 1st answer...................
You can do this by the following interfaces: + (NSBundle *)bundleWithPath:(NSString *)fullPath - (BOOL)load